# Adjusting the MaxHeight of a Table in Dash Tables Python

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

I'm trying to adjust the height of a data table in Dash and it should be pretty straight forward, however no matter what I've tried for a value here, it just keeps outputing all available values.

IF anyone has any ideas it'd be so appreciated. 
I've tried both maxHeight and height, i've tried using the number and the string representation of that number, i've tried numbers from 0 to 100, i've even tried restarting my computer.

```
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(id='raw_data',
                                            data=[],
                                            style_table={
                                                'maxHeight': '5',
                                                'overflowY': 'scroll',
                                            }
                                            ),
                       dcc.Interval(id='interval_component',
                                    interval=60000,
                                    n_intervals=0
                                    )
                       ])
```

Answer (score 4):

try

```
{"selector": ".dash-spreadsheet-inner", 
            "rule":'max-height: "calc(100vh - 226px)"'}],
```

sometimes it helps

**Update**

@Ricardo M S

The solution i found is here: [Dash components follow the .css rules](https://community.plotly.com/t/datepicker-font-control/6607/13)

> In the assets folder of your dash app create a .css file

*any name* .css

my .css file string about table is:

```
/*  высота таблицы Dash DataTable*/
.dash-spreadsheet.dash-freeze-top, .dash-spreadsheet.dash-virtualized 
    { max-height: inherit !important; }

.dash-table-container {max-height: calc(100vh - 225px);}
/*makes the height of the DashTable 225 pix less then the 100% screen */
```

Cheers

Comment: please, provide a full example. Where that dictionary should go on the OP code snippet?

Comment: This is great! Literally, a feature I was trying to add at work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Adding:

```
fixed_rows={ 'headers': True, 'data': 0 }
```

worked for me. In your case:

```
app.layout = html.Div([
                 dash_table.DataTable(
                     id='raw_data',
                     data=[],
                     fixed_rows={ 'headers': True, 'data': 0 },
                     ),
                 dcc.Interval(id='interval_component',
                     interval=60000,
                     n_intervals=0
                     )
                 ])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can adjust the max-height of rows using `css` property of the `DataTable` and use the `selector` and `rule` keys to define Custom CSS Rules.

Example:

```
dash_table.DataTable(
   id='raw_data',
   data=[],
   css=[{"selector": ".dash-table-container tr", 
         "rule":'max-height: "15px"; height: "15px"; '}])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used a string for the maximum height.
'maxHeight': '5',

Also: 5 is probably 5 pixels.
Try instead
'maxHeight': '500',

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).